# How make a auto-login FirebaseAuth (Email/Password) on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make a automatic login to FirebaseAuth but this not works.
When the user enter a Email/Password and check the "Remember-me" I want save the Token for use in the next login (automatic).

I don't know if I save the token in onAuthStateChanged (FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener()) or onComplete (signInWithEmailAndPassword).

So, the app stay like this:

```
prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("quinta", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = prefs.edit();
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if ( user != null ) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"User: " + user.getDisplayName() + ", " + user.getEmail() + " Sign In");
                    String token = user.getToken(true).toString();
                    editor.putString("token",token);
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG,"User: " + user.getDisplayName() + " Sign Out");
                }
            }
        };
```

So, when app opens, I try login:

```
if( prefs.getString("token","aa").length() > 2 ) {
            Log.i(TAG,prefs.getString("token","aa"));
            mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(prefs.getString("token",""));
}
```

and yes, in the Log I check if the prefs.getString("token","") contains the token!
And for end, I reopen the app, and receive the follow error:

```
I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: {
                                                      "error": {
                                                       "errors": [
                                                        {
                                                         "domain": "global",
                                                         "reason": "invalid",
                                                         "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
                                                        }
                                                       ],
                                                       "code": 400,
                                                       "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
                                                      }
                                                     }
```

Comment: When you signIn with firebase the firebase saves user automaticaly so no need of save token. One way to implement wath you want is when app opens check if remenber me is checked if yes start other activity, if no signout and display signin layout. If you want I can create a detailed answer.

Comment: It's works! I'll test other scenarios, but I think that's it! I check if the user != null, so lets to activity!